# load bitmap from url

Tags: java, android, bitmap

i  have problem in bitmap gallery, if i refresh my gallery activity error.
i back from child activity to gallery error..

logcat

```
06-05 03:22:24.848    2366-2366/com.skripsi.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.skripsi.test, PID: 2366
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skripsi.test/com.skripsi.test.Detail_bengkel}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.skripsi.test.GalleryAdapter.loadBitmap(GalleryAdapter.java:63)
            at com.skripsi.test.Detail_bengkel.onCreate(Detail_bengkel.java:138)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5403)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

galleryadapter.java:63

```
String url = getItem(position).toString();
```

detail_bengkel.java:138

```
imageViewURL.setImageBitmap(galleryAdapter.loadBitmap(3));
```

help me..

sorry bad english..

thanks you..

Comment: Your image is encoded byte?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling `getItems` with params `3` which return `null` because there is nothing at that position. You need to access the items in the adapter with a valid index.

For example if you want to display the last image in the adapter in an ImageView.

```
if (galleryAdapter.getCount() > 0){
    imageViewURL.setImageBitmap(galleryAdapter.loadBitmap(galleryAdapter.getCount() - 1));
}
```

Comment: just the same problem

Comment: check the logcat again and see if the error is different